# Does such sequence exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

In analysis course, my professor use a special sequence (in his notes) that I will mention below to prove a theorem.  I can't find any example of such a sequence. I will not bother to mention the full theorem (because I found another proof for it on the internet), but I only want to know does such a sequence $(a_n)$ with below properties exist in real numbers?

- it should be bounded
- $\limsup (a_n)=\sup_{n}a_n=1$
- $\liminf (a_n)=\inf_{n}a_n=-1$
- set of its sequential limit have exactly four elements.

I will appreciate if someone gives me an example.

Comment: Like $-1,0,\frac12, 1, -1,0,\frac12,1,...$?

Comment: or $ a_n=\left \lvert \sin \left(\dfrac{n \pi }6\right)\right \rvert $?

Comment: In future [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) mathjax tutorial will help you to format a better question.

Comment: I meant $a_n=2\left\lvert\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}6\right)\right\rvert-1$

Answer (score 5):

How about $-1,0,\frac12, 1, -1,0,\frac12,1,...$?

Answer (score 1):

Take four non-constant sequences $(x^{(k)}_n), k=0, 1, 2, 3$ that converges to $-1, -\dfrac13, \dfrac13, 1$ respectively. If you want you can impose fuhrer suitable constrains on them. Then take $a_n=x^{(k)}_n$ when $n\equiv k\mod{}4.$